# How to access a nested json from REST API?

Tags: rest, json-server

I'm using json-server to host a json file,  I can fetch the whole file using GET but I don't know how to get access to just a specific nested part of the json. I thought doing http://localhost:3004/data?program=Day%201 would return only the "Day 1" but instead, I got the whole file.What can I do?

```json
{
  "data": {
  "user": {"username": "Pedro", "id":1 },
  "program":{
     "Day 1" :[
        {
          "muscleGroup": "Chest",
          "warmUp": ["parallel bar dips"],
          "main": ["Bench Press", "Inclined Bench press", "Decline Bench press"],
          "secondary": ["Dumbbell Flys", "Cable Crossover Flys", "Pec-deck Fly"]
        },
        {
          "muscleGroup": "Biceps",
          "main": ["Barbell Curl", "Preacher Curl"],
          "secondary": ["Hammer Curls", "Cable Curl", "Dumbbell Curl"]
        }
      ],
      "Day 2" : [
        {
          "muscleGroup": "Shoulders",
          "warmUp": ["parallel bar dips"],
          "main": ["Bench Press", "Inclined Bench press", "Decline Bench press"],
          "secondary": ["Dumbbell Flys", "Cable Crossover Flys", "Pec-deck Fly"]
        },
        {
          "muscleGroup": "Abs",
          "main": ["Crunch", "Leg raises"]
         }
      ],
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that, it is impossible. You need to fetch your json, then get your data.